# on exit event does not fire in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

When I run this code on AWS Lambda nothing gets logged, although when I invoke this locally using serverless (framework), it does log. Is there anything that I am missing?

```
exports.handler = async () => {
  process.on("exit", (code) => {
    console.log("process exit code: ", code);
  });
};
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I believe that you can't process a code once the Lambda code is finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such event in AWS Lambda to know when the container is stopped.
The "Exit" event that fired when you run your code locally it a Node.js event and it is not supported by the AWS Lambda implementation.

You can find here a discussion on how to handle DB connection: [AWS Lambda Container destroy event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45234813/aws-lambda-container-destroy-event)

Answer (score 2):

Lambda endpoints stay alive even after API responds. The actual exit happens when the container that processed the request gets disposed after 15 minutes.