# How can I handle a process exit in an AWS Lambda function in order to flush some data which needs to be sent?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I'm using an analytics library (Segment) to track events in a Lambda function. The library queues up events and batches them periodically. The function regularly exits without flushing all events. I'd like to hook into the process exiting event and flush them before the process exits.

I've attempted to handle the signals which I believe will be sent to a Lambda function on exit, but this code doesn't execute:

```
// handle lambda shutdown to flush events
['SIGINT', 'SIGTERM'].forEach((code) => process.on(code, async () => {
  await analyticsClient.closeAndFlush()
  process.exit()
}))
```

Is it possible to hook into the signals the function process receives on exit? If so, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Lambda supports **graceful shutdown**, for a function with **registered extensions**. When Lambda service is about to shut down the runtime, it sends a **SIGTERM** signal to the runtime and then a **SHUTDOWN**.

In the Shutdown phase, Lambda shuts down the runtime, alerts the extensions to let them stop cleanly, and then removes the environment. Lambda sends a **SHUTDOWN** event to each extension, which tells the extension that the environment is about to be shut down.

Shutdown phase is capped at 2 seconds. If the runtime or any extension does not respond, Lambda terminates it via a signal **SIGKILL**.
The maximum duration of the Shutdown phase depends on the configuration of registered extensions:

- 0 ms – A function with no registered extensions
- 500 ms – A function with a registered internal extension
- 2,000 ms – A function with one or more registered external extensions

You can find more about extensions here: [Runtimes-extensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-extensions-api.html)

The easiest way to test it, is to enable [Amazon CloudWatch Lambda Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Lambda-Insights-Getting-Started-console.html) for existing lambda function.

Example code:

```js
process.on('SIGTERM', async () => {
    // perform actual clean up work here. 
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200));
    process.exit(0)
});
```

[NodeJS sample code](https://github.com/aws-samples/graceful-shutdown-with-aws-lambda/tree/main/nodejs-demo)

Answer (score 0):

For folks using Node and deploying with [SLS](https://www.serverless.com/):

You can install and enable the [serverless-plugin-lambda-insights](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-lambda-insights) plugin. This extension will end up sending a SIGTERM signal to your lambda function that you can listen for:

```js
// Handle SIGTERM signal
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
    console.log('Received SIGTERM signal. Shutting down gracefully...');
    
    // Perform cleanup tasks here
    // For example, closing database connections, releasing resources, etc.

    // Exiting the process
    process.exit(0);
});
```

(I ended up building my own extension until I realized this plugin already did this for me ‍♂️)